# Publish Azure WebRole using Installer (like WIX)

Tags: installation, azure

The requirements for my current project include a Azure WebRole application and also means to install this using a installer.

I've used Wix for previous projects and also published Azure applications (using VS publish) but I'm at a loss at where to start....

Anyone tried publishing Azure WebRole using an installer possibly WIX? What are you're recommendations on this.

Why using an installer? We will be using nightly builds, these builds are version-ed and will be used to installed in DTAP environments. When a version is accepted the same version it can be used to install in production by Application Manager (non-english person here) without the usage of a Visual Studio.

Comment: I don't know of a way to build an installer to publish to Azure but I'm curious how/why you would want to ever do that? Are you expecting the end-user to install into Azure? 

Cloud services should be installed and managed by the vendor or the service provider, not the end-user.

Comment: Even if they did have to be installed by the end user, deploying the app to azure is pretty simple anyway.  Or is this an app that has both client and cloud components?

Comment: Because we have developers who develop and application managers who manage the install to DTAP environments.

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy your service/role to Azure using Service Management API. Write a module which does the deployment and invoke it from WIX.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460807.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've suggested this solution before, but take a look at the [Windows Azure Accelerator for Web Roles](http://waawebroles.codeplex.com/). If nothing else you can call the web deploy from the installer or implement your own deployment module. But at least you have everything else finished.

Comment: The WA projects have been discontinued.