# Deploy a web role on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-web-roles

Below is the task i have to complete in a few weeks, my question is does anyone know of any tutorials or books which will be of use to me? I also only have little knowledge of C#.

> You will design the relevant code in ASP.NET and C# so that you can
>   deploy a web role on Azure that can:
>
> a) read in a zip file from input on the web page
>
> b) uncompress the zip file which will have an executable, an
>   arbitrary list of arguments and data files
>
> c) run the executable with the arguments (and hence read in the
>   data files).
>       d) store the output logs for access later.
>
> You will test this by running a piece of code that reads in a set of
>   arguments which correspond to test files.
>
> The executable will then read in the text files and then print them
>   out.
>
> You will also have to design an appropriate UML to explain how the
>   different classes you have written interact.

Comment: Is this homework, if so you should mark it with the homework task.  I don't think it is asking you to write code to DEPLOY using c#, i think it is asking you to write code is asp.n net and c# that can do a b and c and be deployed as an azure web role.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your service/role to Azure using Service Management API. Write a module which does the deployment and call this in your web.

Check these links that may help you.
[Deploying An Azure Application](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/125435/deploying-an-azure-application/http://www.developerfusion.com/article/125435/deploying-an-azure-application/)
[Publish Azure WebRole using Installer (like WIX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663919/publish-azure-webrole-using-installer-like-wix)
[About the Service Management API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460807.aspx)

> The Windows Azure Accelerator for Web Roles makes it quick and easy
>   for you to deploy one or more websites across multiple Web Role
>   instances using Web Deploy. The accelerator includes a Visual Studio
>   project template that creates a Windows Azure web role to host one or
>   more websites.

[Azure Tutorial; Be in cloud (Part 3) [Web Role]](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/144367/Azure-Tutorial-Be-in-cloud-Part-3-Web-Role)
[Windows Azure and SQL Azure Tutorials - Tutorial 1: Using Windows Azure Web Role and Windows Azure Table Service](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2128.aspx)

Check [Azure in Action](http://www.manning.com/hay/) Book and it's [content](http://www.manning.com/hay/excerpt_contents.html).

Hope these help you to get an idea that you want to implement.

Answer (score 0):

That's hard homework: *Upload a zip file to a cloud based server and run the .exe*. Interesting...

Anyway, the [Azure SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/sdk/) is a great place to start. Also scan through Smarx's [Cloud Cover](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Cloud+Cover/) shows. They cover pretty much everything.