# Deploy a web role in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

Below is the task i have to complete in a few weeks, my question is does anyone know of any tutorials or books which will be of use to me? I also only have little knowledge of C#.

> You will design the relevant code in ASP.NET and C# so that you can
>   deploy a web role on Azure that can:
>
> a) read in a zip file from input on the web page
>
> b) uncompress the zip file which will have an executable, an arbitrary
>   list of arguments and data files
>
> c) run the executable with the arguments (and hence read in the data
>   files). d) store the output logs for access later.
>
> You will test this by running a piece of code that reads in a set of
>   arguments which correspond to test files.
>
> The executable will then read in the text files and then print them
>   out.
>
> You will also have to design an appropriate UML to explain how the
>   different classes you have written interact.

Comment: If it is a homework, it should be tagged as such.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deploy a web role on Azure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413861/deploy-a-web-role-on-azure)

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out the [Windows Azure Training Kit](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/other-resources/training-kit/)?

Comment: +1 - if the question is about where to learn about Windows Azure (vs. solving your specific homework challenge), the training kit is the best place to start.